# Unity 3D How to setup Turret Auto Aim? C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

what i't trying to achieve is have my turrent rotate and follow an "Enemy".

At the moment it detects the enemy but it is not rotating and I don't know why.

The bullet it a prefab i drag in, there has to be a better way to do this? Anyone have any suggestions please?

At the moment the bullet never triggers, but the log Shoot and does...and the rotate doesn't work.

Here is what i have

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TurretController : MonoBehaviour {

    public Rigidbody bulletPrefab;
    private Transform target;
    private GameObject bullet;
    private float nextFire;
    private Quaternion targetPos;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider otherCollider) {
        if (otherCollider.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            Debug.Log ("in");
            target = otherCollider.transform;
            StartCoroutine ("Fire");
        }
    }

    void  OnTriggerExit(Collider otherCollider) {
        if (otherCollider.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            Debug.Log ("out");
            target = null;
            StopCoroutine("Fire"); // aborts the currently running Fire() coroutine
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Fire()
    {
        while (target != null)
        {
            nextFire = Time.time + 0.5f;
            while (Time.time < nextFire)
            {
                // smooth the moving of the turret
                targetPos = Quaternion.LookRotation (target.position);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetPos, Time.deltaTime * 5);
                yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            }
            // fire!
            Debug.Log ("shoot");
            bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            //bullet.rigidbody.velocity = transform.forward * bulletSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change the instantiate part by using this instead

```
bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate(bulletPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            bullet.GetComponent<Bullet>().target = target.transform;
```

But then i just get errors like "InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
TurretController+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/TurretController.cs:44)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BTW, here's the turret rotation code I used in my project (shared with permission):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Turret : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float turnRateRadians = 2 * Mathf.PI;

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform turretTop; // the gun part that rotates

    [SerializeField]
    private Transform bulletSpawnPoint;

    private Enemy target;

    void Update()
    {
        TargetEnemy();
    }

    void TargetEnemy()
    {
        if (target == null || target.health <= 0)
            target = Enemy.GetClosestEnemy(turretTop, filter: enemy => enemy.health > 0);

        if (target != null)
        {
            Vector3 targetDir = target.transform.position - transform.position;
            // Rotating in 2D Plane...
            targetDir.y = 0.0f;
            targetDir = targetDir.normalized;

            Vector3 currentDir = turretTop.forward;

            currentDir = Vector3.RotateTowards(currentDir, targetDir, turnRateRadians*Time.deltaTime, 1.0f);

            Quaternion qDir = new Quaternion();
            qDir.SetLookRotation(currentDir, Vector3.up);
            turretTop.rotation = qDir;
        }
    }
}

class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health = 0;

    private static HashSet<Enemy> allEnemies = new HashSet<Enemy>();

    void Awake()
    {
        allEnemies.Add(this);
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        allEnemies.Remove(this);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the closest enemy to some transform, optionally filtering
    /// (for example, enemies that aren't dead, or enemies of a certain type).
    /// </summary>
    public static Enemy GetClosestEnemy(Transform referenceTransform, System.Predicate<Enemy> filter=null)
    {
        // Left as an exercise for the reader.
        // Remember not to use Vector3.Distance in a loop if you don't need it. ;-)
//      return allEnemies[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mate, I shall try to pull this apart soon. Really helps as i could not find too much on the interwebs written in C#

Comment: Welcome! I actually don't remember why we used `SetLookRotation()` instead of `transform.forward=`, so you could try it both ways.

Comment: I use transform.forward at the moment, My code works, However I didn;t have any logic for multiple enemies and when my tower was shooting and another walked in it just snapped to it immediately. What i want to do is add logic similar to BloonsTD game, where as the user has an option to choose if the towers attack the most furthest along enemy or if they attack the strongest or weakest first....Thanks again.

Comment: That sounds like an easy change. Right now once it picks a target, it keeps shooting at that enemy until it's dead. That can also be changed.

Answer (score 1):

First problem: the bullet prefab. The variable type is `RigidBody`. If you want to treat it as a game object, the variable must be a game object. Or you can instantiate it, cast to `RigidBody`, then use the `.gameObject` accessor. Like this:

```
((RigidBody)Instantiate(theRigidbody)).gameObject
```

Second problem: start simple with the rotation. If it's not working, don't get fancy yet. Start with something like this (an instant rotation toward the target):

```
Vector3 targetDirection = target.transform.position - transform.position;
targetDirection.y = 0; // optional: don't look up
transform.forward = targetDirection;
```

If it works, then add small pieces of additional complexity until it does exactly what you want. And if you don't get things figured out, give me a shout (a comment) on Monday. I've written turret-aiming code (including a maximum rotation speed), and I don't think my boss would mind if I upload it.

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, that's definitely something you should ask your lawyers about if you're not 100% sure.

Comment: Yeah i been bashing my head on the keyboard for a few hrs now, trying to get this right haha. I would love it if you could send that to me on monday.. :P

Comment: Also yes please make sure you won't get into trouble for me.. haha, I tried i tried changing it to GameObject instead of rigidbody and change the aiming code, No it seems to aim for a second but then throws an error and still doesn't shoot.

ALso i just realised that my bullet is a prefab that heads towards it target, and originaly i had my turret set the target of the bullet, but i tried to hack this code up I never attempted to pass a target to the bullet, Check the edit in few minutes and i shall post updated code.

Comment: I have changed to try some different code and now i just get an error
"InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
TurretController+<Fire>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/TurretController.cs:47)
"

http://jsfiddle.net/45quae96/

Comment: Haha, I'll be quite sure after I ask the boss. When it comes to posting small self-contained pieces of code, he hasn't ever said no. @MIke, when you changed the type of `bulletPrefab` to `GameObject`, did you re-link it in the inspector? Some versions of Unity have a bug where the inspector won't even show you there's a problem, but an old link to a different type (on the same object) is never valid data. It will not automatically correct itself, either.

Comment: You rock mate, It seemed to have worked I relinked the script and the bullet and then it started shooting.. Nice thanks heaps Bud... I would still love to see how you do it though as my hacked code is terrible haha

Comment: @MIke I'll post it when I'm at work, but I can't promise mine will be any less hacked. It looks good (it works) but I don't remember how I wrote it! :D